# Qt 5.10 'delete' keypress not detected

Tags: qt

Please note: I am quite new to Qt, and working within an already-existing project.  Please forgive any apparent noob-isms.

I am attempting to delete an entry (or entries) in a tree-view filesystem dialog.  This builds without error, but doesn't seem to do anything:

```
QShortcut *m_DeleteKeyAction;
m_DeleteKeyAction = new QShortcut(this);
m_DeleteKeyAction->setKey(Qt::Key_Delete);
connect(m_DeleteKeyAction, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(deleteTriggered()));
```

I know the SLOT functions correctly, as I am able to perform that function using a right-click menu.  I just wanted to add Delete-key functionality to this dialog.

For a separate part of this project, I'm looking to do something similar, but rather than deleting files, I want to move an entry from one list to a blacklist and back again, using the Delete key

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I just tested your code and it works correctly. I've tested it on Linux with Qt 5.10. If you provide the project code through a zip file, you can check what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried other buttons? in what widgets are you using it?

Comment: Probably key event is swallowing by another widget or your key event occurs in the context where this shortcut is inactive. Try to change the shortcut's key or play with shortcut's context (`QShortcut::setContext()`).

Comment: @eyllanesc - As this is a collaborative effort, I'm not comfortable handing out the project source.  As for what widget I'm trying to get this to work in, it appears to be a "QDialog" widget, if that helps.  I'm still new to this language, so please bear with me if I am incorrect there.

Comment: @vahancho - How can I determine current context, and where might I find a list of valid contexts to test in this circumstance?  Thanks.

Comment: For me there is no problem, do not make an excuse that is new in the language or Qt, it is not a real excuse, I have tried it and it works correctly, if it is collaborative I suppose there are other people who know more about the topic so ask them if they have implemented correctly. Your code looks good but I can not reproduce your error so SO suggests that you provide a [mcve], that is, a project that may be different from the original that reproduces your error.

Comment: [cont] I suggested that you share the project with me because the beginners usually have problems with this type of problems and the cause is in a part of the code that they do not show so I wanted to save time in asking you questions. Also, I recommend you to know your project well, to tell me that "apparently it's a QDialog" sounds like a lack of professionalism.